# How to decode hex encoded Cyrillic string?

Tags: python, unicode, hex, decode

I have a hex encoded Cyrillic string "041E043F043B04300442".

How can I convert into a text string?

I tried this way:

```
codecs.decode('041E043F043B04300442', 'hex').decode('utf-16')
'Ḅ㼄㬄〄䈄'
```

But I'm getting wrong symbols.
As I see from the Unicode symbols list, the first symbol should be a Cyrillic symbol:

```
U+041E  Cyrillic Capital Letter O
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had to use another codec:

```
codecs.decode('041E043F043B04300442', 'hex').decode('utf-16be')
```

Now it is being decoded fine.

Answer (score 0):

`utf-16` defaults to the machine's endian-ness unless a byte order mark (BOM, U+FEFF) is present.  Your machine appears to be little-endian, but the data is big-endian:

```py
>>> bytes.fromhex("041E043F043B04300442").decode('utf-16')
'Ḅ㼄㬄〄䈄'
>>> bytes.fromhex("041E043F043B04300442").decode('utf-16le')
'Ḅ㼄㬄〄䈄'
>>> bytes.fromhex("041E043F043B04300442").decode('utf-16be')
'Оплат'
```

(English) payment

With a correct BOM added, `utf-16` can work:

```py
>>> bytes.fromhex("FEFF041E043F043B04300442").decode('utf-16')
'Оплат'
```